# Count months from a date to December then count months from January the following year to December that same year, then from January to end date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a start_date of 1/10/2018, and an end_date of 1/8/2020, the difference between the two dates in months is 22, that is 1 year 10 months, now, I want to create tables that terminate at the end of each year as follows:

table 1
column_heading  will be "1/10/2018 - 31/12/2018"
and the row  will be "2 months"

table 2
column_heading  will be "1/1/2019 - 31/12/2019"
and the row  will be "12 months"

table 3
column_heading  will be "1/1/2020 - 1/8/2020"
and the row  will be "8 months"

I would like to loop **something**, maybe the **difference between the dates** to create the number of tables necessary, if the two dates exist within the same year it will only create 1 table, or 2 if it enters the next year, I am using laravel and carbon to manipulate the dates.

Thank you in anticipation of your help.

Something like this
[image]

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way. Note that I had to convert the format of your dates to YYYY-mm-dd in order to use PHP date functions. In the end you'll get an array and it's easy for you to transform the final dates into the format you desire. You can test it here: https://www.tehplayground.com/lvuTdWl91TeItEQC

The code:

```
<?php
// example code

$s = "1/10/2018";
$e = "1/08/2020";

// reassemble so we can use the date functions YYYY-mm-dd
$s = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $s)) );
$e = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $e)) );
 
// get the parts separated
$start = explode("-",$s);
$end = explode("-",$e) ;

$iterations = ((intVal($end[0]) - intVal($start[0])) * 12) - (intVal($start[1]) - intVal($end[1])) ;

$sets=[$start[0] => array("start" => $s, "end" => "", "months" => 0)];
$curdstart= $curd = $s;
$curyear = date("Y", strtotime($s));

for($x=1; $x<=$iterations; $x++) {
    $curdend = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($curd . " +{$x} months"));
    $curyear = date("Y", strtotime($curdend));
    if (!isset($sets[$curyear])) {
        $sets[$curyear]= array("start" => $curdend, "end" => "", "months" => 0);
    }
    $sets[$curyear]['months']++;
    $sets[$curyear]['end'] = date("Y-m-", strtotime($curdend)) . "31";
    
}

die(print_r($sets,1));
$mctr = 0 ;
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [2018] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2018-10-1
            [end] => 2018-12-31
            [months] => 2
        )

    [2019] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2019-01-01
            [end] => 2019-12-31
            [months] => 12
        )

    [2020] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2020-01-01
            [end] => 2020-08-31
            [months] => 8
        )

)
```